# MUI - React Custom Input not updating when setting value with

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, material-ui

I am using React Hook Forms and MUI React, I have a custom input wrapper which looks something like this:

```
const CustomInput: React.FC<IInputProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    label,
    readonly,
    name,
    placeholder,
    hint,
    control,
    required,
    type,
    onValueChange,
  } = props;

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={{ required: required }}
      render={({ field: { value, onChange }, fieldState }) => (
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          InputProps={{
            readOnly: readonly,
          }}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          value={value}
          label={label}
          onChange={(event) => {
            onChange(event);
            if (onValueChange) {
              onValueChange(event);
            }
          }}
          helperText={fieldState.error ? 'my multi line error component' : hint}
          error={fieldState.error && true}
          type={type}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomInput;
```

I have a form to create an invoice, which consists of a Field Array (invoice line items).
Each line item has a quantity, item price and total.
What I intend to do is for the user to input the Item Price and Quantity, then calculate the Total and display it in the Input, so I did this:

```
  const handleOnChange = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);

    const quantity = watch(`lineItems.${index}.quantity`);
    const unitPrice = watch(`lineItems.${index}.pricePerItem`);
    const total = calculateTotal(unitPrice, quantity);
    setValue(`lineItems[${index}].totalAmount`, total.toFixed(2));
  };
```

Now, this does work - but it is not reflecting the updated value in the input, BUT if I display the value as a label ( it shows the correct value.

This Works!:

```
   <p>{getValues(`lineItems.${index}.totalAmount`)}</p>
```

This doesn't show the updated value

```
    <CustomInput
      readonly
      label="total"
      name={`lineItems.${index}.totalAmount`}
      control={control}
    />
```

[image]

What am I missing?

I've created an example in stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j11jc4?file=src%2Fcustom-input.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is pretty simple since you have unnecessary square brackets `[]` when setting the value:

```
setValue(`lineItems[${index}].totalAmount`, total.toFixed(2));
```

should be

```
setValue(`lineItems.${index}.totalAmount`, total.toFixed(2));
```

However not exactly sure why you want to keep that value in the *form* state. It's a `read-only` value and you are just displaying it. I'd go with the simple `p` element to show the total value.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes typos just get missed.  This is just an example of the problem, my case is a bit different where I would want user to sometimes override the calculated value, but to replicate the example as simple as possible for SO this is what I came up with.